# Can users with a custom role approve the user registration?

Tags: users

I have created a site that requires approval of new user registrations. I added the *Manager* role for the site owner. I'd like users with that role to approve the account registrations.

Is there any configuration that will give another role the permission to approve new user registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the **Permissions** screen at `/admin/people/permissions`, you can give the permission **Administer users** to the Manager role.

**Administer users** is an administrator permission, but you do not need to give the other administrator permissions to the **Manager** role.

If you really don't want the **Manager** role to have unlimited access to user accounts, you could use the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO) module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and [code a custom action](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/views-bulk-operations-vbo/creating-a-new-action) to allow managers to unblock new user accounts.  You will need to code a custom action because the VBO module includes an unblock users action by default, but this requires **Administer users** permission.

Comment: Thank you! I've chosen the second option...